# Filter Transactions occurring on a set of dates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a query which I am using to aggregate amount of transactions falling on dates.
Now I wish to use $match to filter the transactions falling on a set of dates.

The dates column raised_date is a timestamp, so I use `$toDate` first to convert it to date and format it to a date string.

My working aggregate query for calculating amount totals on dates is like so -

```
db.transactions.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                date: {
                    "$toDate": "$raised_date"
                }
            }
        },
        amount_total: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
}])
```

It gives me data :

```
{ "_id" : "2019-05-13", "amount_total" : 2000 }
{ "_id" : "2019-05-28", "amount_total" : 78 }
{ "_id" : "2019-09-19", "amount_total" : 3000 }
{ "_id" : "2019-01-05", "amount_total" : 9034 }
{ "_id" : "2019-04-15", "amount_total" : 2600 }
{ "_id" : "2019-11-14", "amount_total" : 2870 }
{ "_id" : "2019-09-16", "amount_total" : 1500 }
{ "_id" : "2019-09-18", "amount_total" : 7200 }
{ "_id" : "2019-04-11", "amount_total" : 106034 }
{ "_id" : "2019-03-13", "amount_total" : 2000 }
{ "_id" : "2019-04-30", "amount_total" : 2302 }
{ "_id" : "2019-01-08", "amount_total" : 4665 }
{ "_id" : "2019-05-03", "amount_total" : 83 }
{ "_id" : "2019-08-03", "amount_total" : 2500 }
{ "_id" : "2019-03-04", "amount_total" : 350930 }
{ "_id" : "2019-12-10", "amount_total" : 1819 }
{ "_id" : "2019-03-12", "amount_total" : 15002 }
{ "_id" : "2019-05-08", "amount_total" : 78 }
{ "_id" : "2019-12-12", "amount_total" : 2370 }
```

Then I am able to filter these transactions based on dates like this

```
db.transactions.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                date: {
                    "$toDate": "$raised_date"
                }
            }
        },
        amount_total: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        _id: {
            $in: ["2019-05-13"]
        }
    }
}])
```

Which gives me data :

```
{ "_id" : "2019-05-13", "amount_total" : 2000 }
```

I believe it is better to filter data before the aggregations, in huge tables, so I wish to add a $match query at the start.

Now I am trying to modify it to filter data based on a set of dates using a match query. How do I filter records where I need to modify the values in the columns and check if they are in a list of dates.

```
db.transactions.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        {
              "$dateToString": {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: {
                  "$toDate": "$raised_date"
              }
          }
        }: {
            $in: ["2019-05-13"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                date: {
                    "$toDate": "$raised_date"
                }
            }
        },
        amount_total: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
}])
```

I haven't worked a lot on mongodb as yet. Just figuring it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `$match` before grouping, MongoDB can apply index if you have defined for `raised_date` field. Once you tansform your data, indexes cannot be applied.

Try this one:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          raised_date: {
            $gte: ISODate("2019-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2019-01-05T23:59:59Z")
          }
        },
        {
          raised_date: {
            $gte: ISODate("2019-05-13T00:00:00Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2019-05-13T23:59:59Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$dateToString": {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            "$toDate": "$raised_date"
          }
        }
      },
      amount_total: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhGFfcCohdM)

**Note:** Filtering by `raised_date` date conversion into string should be matched with `$expr` operator like this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          {
            "$dateToString": {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: {
                "$toDate": "$raised_date"
              }
            }
          },
          [
            "2019-05-13", "2019-01-05"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$dateToString": {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            "$toDate": "$raised_date"
          }
        }
      },
      amount_total: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UAU7Z9xJUew)

Answer (score 1):

I used project to convert the timestamps to dates, and then filter them with the list of dates , followed by aggregation.

```
[{
    $project: {
        "raised_date": {
            "$dateToString": {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                date: {
                    "$toDate": "$raised_date"
                }
            }
        },
        "amount": 1
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        raised_date: {
            $in: ["2019-05-13", "2019-01-05"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$raised_date",
        amount_total: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
}]
```

If there is a better way to do this , do post it as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

after aggregate function you have to use a projection method for your answer